# DataGridViewRowsAdded handler gives errors

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, addhandler

I'm trying to add the `RowsAdded` and `CellFormatting` handlers to my project. I seem to have cleared up all errors in the `CellFormatting` handler but my `RowsAdded` is giving some errors that I cannot figure out.

> Argument not specified for parameter 'rowCount' of 'Public Sub
>   New(rowIndex As Integer, rowCount As Integer)'
>
> 'AddressOf' expression cannot be converted to 'Integer' because 'Integer' is not a delegate type

My code:

```
Private Sub InitializeDataGridView()
    Try
        ' Set up the DataGridView. 
        With Me.DataGridView1
            ' Automatically generate the DataGridView columns.
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True

            ' Set up the data source.
            .DataSource = dt

            ' Automatically resize the visible rows.
            .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders

            ' Set the DataGridView control's border.
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D

            ' Put the cells in edit mode when user enters them.
            .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2

            ' Disables Add New Row
            .AllowUserToAddRows = False

            '.AllowUserToOrderColumns = False
            For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
                column.SortMode = _
                DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
            Next

            AddHandler Me.DataGridView1.CellFormatting, New DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(AddressOf OnCellFormatting)
            AddHandler Me.DataGridView1.RowsAdded, New DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs(AddressOf OnRowsAdded)

        End With

    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, _
            "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()
    End Try
End Sub
```

And

```
Private Sub OnCellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    'If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView1.Columns("Contact").Index Then
    '    e.FormattingApplied = True
    '    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    '    e.Value = String.Format("{0} : {1}", row.Cells("ContactName").Value, row.Cells("Phone").Value)
    'End If
End Sub
Private Sub OnRowsAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded
    'For i As Integer = 0 To e.RowIndex - 1
    '    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex + i)
    '    row.Cells("Contact").Value = String.Format("{0} : {1}", row.Cells("ContactName").Value, row.Cells("Phone").Value)
    'Next
End Sub
```

In regards to the errors, I'm not using rowCount anywhere so maybe I need to?

Why does it think I using integer as a delegate type?

I checked and I don't have any public variable rowCount or rowIndex.

---

Per the answer I deleted the two lines in Sub InitializeDataGridView() which seems to fix my errors. However the answer also states that Args should be Handler. So I changed the Private Sub OnRowsAdded to

```
Private Sub OnRowsAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler) Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded
    For i As Integer = 0 To e.RowIndex - 1
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex + i)
        row.Cells("Contact").Value = String.Format("{0} : {1}", row.Cells("ContactName").Value, row.Cells("Phone").Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Which caused a bunch of new errors, so I undid it. Why does that cause errors though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one *typo* in the `InitializeDataGridView` method:

```
AddHandler Me.DataGridView1.RowsAdded, New DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs(AddressOf OnRowsAdded)
```

Should be:

```
AddHandler Me.DataGridView1.RowsAdded, New DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(AddressOf OnRowsAdded)
                                                                      ^^^^^^
```

Also, the event handler is already connected via the `Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded` and `Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting`at the end of your `OnRowAdded` and `OnCellFormatting` methods, so you don't need to *attach* the event handler a second time. These two (*corrected*) lines are finally unnecessary:

```
AddHandler Me.DataGridView1.CellFormatting, New DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(AddressOf OnCellFormatting)
AddHandler Me.DataGridView1.RowsAdded, New DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(AddressOf OnRowsAdded)
```

Comment: I deleted the two unnecessary rows and it was fixed! The private sub onrowsadded still needs Args instead of Handler or more errors arise. Can that be explained?

Comment: @ZL1Corvette  Unless I dont understand your question, the answer is on the first part of my answer (typo Args vs Handler).

Comment: I change the Args to Handler in the Sub OnRowAdded and got errors. Details in original post.

Comment: @ZL1Corvette OK, Got it. You need to change `...Args` to `...Handler` in the InitializeDataGridView method *only*. The `Private Sub OnRowsAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs)` method was OK before the edit.